# How to reformat dates without NA's

Tags: r, date

I have a column of dates I need to reformat, they are in the format  m/d/yyyy, but as the dates grow the format becomes mm/dd/yyyy.  When I try to run

```
as.Date(x, format = '%m/%d/%y')
```

I get NA's

How can I reformat the dates to mm/dd/yyyy?

Comment: Have you tried the lubridate package? In this case the `mdy` function, which is quite forgiving, should work.

Comment: Are you sure they are m/d/y not d/m/y?.  There shouldn't be any problem otherwise, for example: `as.Date("10/20/2020", format = '%m/%d/%y')` works fine.

Comment: as @sashahafner said, the lubridate package in combination with the tidyverse package will probably do the trick.  R for Data Science (https://r4ds.had.co.nz/) also has a chapter about using these packages for dates and times (Ch. 16).

Comment: It would be @easyier to help if you post sample data ;) And you might try a capital `"%Y"`, i.e. `as.Date(x, format = "%m/%d/%Y")`

Comment: @markus is right. There should be no need to change m/d/ to mm/dd. Try this: `x <- c('3/14/2022', '04/01/2022', '04/2/2018', '10/11/2019') ; as.Date(x, format = '%m/%d/%Y')`

Comment: Thanks all! the mdy() seemed to work

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
# convert date info in format 'mm/dd/yyyy'
  strDates <- c("01/05/1965", "08/16/1975")
  
  strDates
```

Output:

```
[1] "01/05/1965" "08/16/1975"
```

Convert the dates using this code:

```
dates <- as.Date(strDates, "%m/%d/%Y")
```

Output:

```
[1] "1965-01-05" "1975-08-16"
```